# Unable to store GCP DLP de-identification template to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to create a Dataflow in GCP using Terraform.

In Terraform, the Dataflow resource requires one mandatory field "template_gcs_path" which indicates the google cloud storage path to de-identification template.

I can not move this template to google cloud storage, hence unable to create the Dataflow job using Terraform.

Code template:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "big_data_job" {
  name              = "dataflow-job"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://my-bucket/templates/template_file" <-- [This is where I am stuck]
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://my-bucket/tmp_dir"
  parameters = {
    foo = "bar"
    baz = "qux"
  }
}
```

How to resolve this?

**NOTE:** I am trying to do the entire flow using terraform.

Comment: Hi! First a clarifying question: is your inability to use GCS a company policy, or a technical limitation?

Comment: You look like you are trying to create a dataflow job, but terraform doesn't have built in support via terraform for Cloud DLP.  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataflow_flex_template_job.    https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/data_loss_prevention_job_trigger